# Solving Trigonometric word problems with limited information

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

[This is a diagram of this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDrON.png)
[image]

The word Problem:

Andrew wants to construct a new stairway to the front door of his house. The door is 3 feet above the ground and at an angle of $30^{\circ}$ to the sidewalk, as shown in the diagram. Let’s help him find how far from the house he needs to begin the stairway. The stairway will make an angle of $30^{\circ}$ with the ground. The angle between the ground and the front of the house is $90^{\circ}$. So, we have a $30^{\circ}-60^{\circ}-90^{\circ}$ triangle. We know the angle and the side opposite to it. We need to find the adjacent side. We know that in a right triangle, the tangent function is the ratio of the opposite side to the adjacent side. So we can use that ratio to find the adjacent side:

What I know how to do:

I know that I have to use the trigonometric function tangent to solve this problem because I am only given the opposite side and I need to solve for the adjacent side of the staircase.

tan $30^{\circ} = 3/x$

So I solve for x and get

$x = 3/x$

The notes that this problem is based on already gives the answer to the problem but I am stuck on this part of the explanation where its showing how to solve for x.
[This is where I am stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztQVE.png)

I don't understand how $\tan 30^{\circ} = 1/\sqrt{3}$.

Is it radians or am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site.  To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs.  For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$.  You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: $\tan30^\circ=\frac{\sin30^\circ}{\cos30^\circ}=\frac{1/2}{\sqrt3/2}=\frac1{\sqrt3}$

Comment: Draw an equilateral triangle and cut it in half to see why $\tan 30^\circ =1/\sqrt 3$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a $30^{\circ}$-$60^{\circ}$-$90^{\circ}$ triangle, so the sides are proportional to $\frac12,\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},1$, right?

In particular, $\sin 30^{\circ} = \frac12$ and $\cos 30^{\circ}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, so $\tan 30^{\circ} =\frac{\sin 30^{\circ}}{\cos 30^{\circ}}= \frac{1/2}{\sqrt{3}/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: That makes sense but it doesn't say that the triangle's hypotenuse's length is 1 unit or does it matter if the lengths of the 30-60-90 triangle are different.

Comment: Since it is a 30-60-90 triangle, you know the hypotenuse is determined by the other legs as $\sqrt{(\frac12)^2 + (\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2} = \sqrt{\frac14+\frac34}= \sqrt{1} = 1$. 
Even if all sides are scaled up by the same factor, their *ratios* are still the same as these, so when you compute the sine or cosine or tangent as a ratio of two sides, you'll get the same answer (the scale factors from the two sides will cancel, leaving the same ratio).